# Регулярные выражения: создать общую группу, в которую не добавляются символы из вложенной группы. (.Net)

Tags: .net, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Приходит имя файла которое, в идеальном виде, имеет формат "[2013]Test1 [23.12.2020 13-34].zip",
где:

1. [2013] - Id *(в результате должно попасть в группу "id" без "[]")*
2. Test1 - Имя файла *(в результате должно попасть в группу "name")*
3. [23.12.2020 13-34] - Дата *(в результате должно попасть в группу "date" без "[]")*
4. .zip - расширение *(в результате должно попасть в группу "ext")*

И есть ряд правил:

1. Расширение (.zip или иное) всегда присутствует
2. Группа "name" может быть пустой *(формат [2013][23.12.2020 13-34].zip)*
3. Группы "id" и "date" необязательные и если они не найдены все должно попадать в группу "name" *(форматы: "Test1 [23.12.2020 13-34].zip", "[2013]Test1 .zip", "Test1 .zip")*
4. Могут отсутствовать все группу кроме расширения *(формат ".zip")*

К тому-же если формат: "[]Test1 [].zip", то группа "name" = "[]Test1 []", либо формат: "Te[]st[] 1.zip", то группа "name" = "Te[]st[] 1" (Выходит символы "[" и "]" не могут быть ограничениями для группы "name").

Я пробовал решить вопрос так :
`(?:\[+(?'id'[0-9]*)\]+)?(?'name'[^]]*)?(?:\[+(?'data'[.\-:0-9]*)\]+)?(?'ext'\.[.a-zA-Z]+)+`

При таком решение группа "name" ограничена символом "]", что не совсем подходит.
Необходимо строго отслеживать отсутствие групп "id" и "date" и добавлять весь оставшийся текст в группу "name" (если вообще хоть что-то осталось).
Не знаю как такого добиться, но идея в создании вложенных групп исключающие символы из базовой в случае их попадания в них.

Возможно ли вообще подобное решить с помощью регулярных выражений?

> ```
> Для примеров:
> [2013]Test1 [23.12.2020 13-34].zip
> [2013]Test1 .zip
> Test1 [23.12.2020 13-34].zip
> Test1 .zip
> []Test1 [].zip
> Te[]st[]1 .zip
> [][].zip
> [].zip
> .zip
> ```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/3hXVFU/1 - можно попробовать настроить как вам нужно тут

Comment: @PotroNik Спасибо. Я пользуюсь этим сайтом. Но я не знаю как конкретно построить выражение, чтобы оно выполняло все условия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решение:**

```
^(?:\[(?'id'[0-9]+)\])?(?'name'[^[.]+|.+)?(?:\[(?'data'[.\-:0-9 ]+)\])?(?'ext'\.[.a-zA-Z]+)+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/CTLULd/1

Таким способом соблюдаются условия и отрабатывают все примеры. Это мне и нужно было.

@PotroNik Спасибо. Ответ был так близок: `[^\.]` (иногда "глаз замыливается")